# Capture an Impulse (As Opposed to an Impulse Response)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, impact

I want to see if there's a method by which you could capture the characteristics of an impulse source, rather than the response of the system to the impulse.

Normally, when attempting to capture an impulse response, an idealized impulse source (i.e. sine wave) is played through a room or other medium, and the response of the room/medium are captured.

Instead of capturing the response to the impulse, **I want to capture the characteristics of the impulse itself**, i.e. the hammer on the piano, or the impulse of a train rolling over tracks, and then be able to translate those impulses across mediums. Any kind of mechanical impact between objects.

Rather than modeling the physics of the impulse source, I'd imagine building a testing rig of some kind to capture the impulses across a range of amplitudes and then be able to interpolate across that range.

What methods could be used for this purpose?

Comment: Why do you say "idealized impulse source (i.e. sine wave)"? Doesn't impulse look like a spike rather than a sine wave?

Comment: What do you mean by "able to translate those impulses across mediums"?

Comment: To capture impulse source characteristics, on cloud use sensors or high-speed cameras. For interpolating, use experiments or machine learning to quantify the relationship between impulse properties and the resulting response in a medium.